# Unchecking Rich Text option to clean up HTML still cleaning?

Tags: field, richtext

We've unchecked the clean HTML feature on a few rich text fields but our attempts to add some html (span tags) keep getting cleaned out. Is there another setting we should be looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I came upon this issue when wrapping copy with a span tag in order to style it differently. The span tag was removed when I saved the entry.

By design, Redactor removes span tags that don't have attributes. The fix is to edit the Redactor config file and add the [**removeWithoutAttr**](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-removeWithoutAttr) config as an empty array.

```
removeWithoutAttr: []
```

This prevents tags without attributes from being removed by Redactor.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a custom redactor config (defined in /craft/config/redactor) and it has `allowedTags` in the configuration, that list of allowed tags will need to include span

Comment: Sorry to circle back so late. Auto notifications weren't on. We don't have anything defined there, so that's not the case. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Chris sorry, no other thoughts

Comment: Maybe the [removeEmpty](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-removeEmpty) setting will help

Answer (score 1):

Best I can figure it's either:

1. A Redactor bug
2. A known behavior and Redactor just *really* doesn't like `<span></span>` tags.

Even if you explicitly set Redactor's [allowedTags](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/#set-allowedTags) config setting to include span, they will strip it out simply swapping between source and rendered view, whereas any other tag I set in that list will be allowed as expected.